# undefined method using activemodel and form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an ActiveModel class that represent and email message and a form that submits a message with a hidden field for useremail. When I submit my form I get a

```
undefined method `receiver=' for <Message:0x007fce44d495f8>
```

.

```
class Message
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :contenu

  validates :name, 
            :presence => true

  validates :email,
            :format => { :with => /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9a-z\-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\z/ }

  validates :content,
            :length => { :minimum => 10, :maximum => 1000 }


  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end


   def persisted?
     false
    end

end
```

My form:

```
<%= form_for @message, :url => {:action => "contact"}, :method => "post" do |f| %>

   <% @message.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <p><%= msg %></p>
   <% end %>


   <%= f.hidden_field :receiver, :value => @listing.user.email  %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :contenu, "Message" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :contenu %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Send Message" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your messgae doesn't contain a receiver field. If you want it to containt, then add it in the database. If it is only a temporary data for the form and controller code, then use `hidden_field_tag` instead of `f.hidden_field`. The later is only good for fields of the model.